# Thin/Hair space in FPDF

Tags: utf-8, fpdf, iso-8859-1

I was wondering if it's possible to add a thin/hair space to a PDF generated by FPDF?

I already tried

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', html_entity_decode('bla&thinsp;blub'))
```

but this gives me:

```
PHP Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string
```

(My font was generated with `ISO-8859-1`)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, answering my own question: I found an [addon](http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/62/) which allows to fit a text in a cell by reducing space width and/or character spacing. It does it by writing raw PDF source.

In my case this helped out, but doesn't really answer the question...